# My react app is showing a blank page on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my chat application folder, I have a client\my-app and a server folder. In the client folder, I have other folders called node modules, public, and src. I also have a .gitignore, package-lock.json, package.json, and readme.md. Within the src, I have a components folder, an App.jsx, and an index.js. Within the components folder, I have a ChannelContainer.jsx, a ChannelListContainer.jsx, and an index.js.

This is my App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import { StreamChat } from 'stream-chat';
import { Chat } from 'stream-chat-react';

import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

import { ChannelListContainer, ChannelContainer } from './components';

const apiKey = '98dzy6uqhm8m';

const client = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey);

console.log("hi")

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="app__wrapper">
            <Chat client={client} theme="team light">
                <ChannelListContainer
                    
                    />
                <ChannelContainer
                    />
            </Chat>
            
            </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is the index.js that is in the src folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is the index.js that is in the components folder:

```
export { default as ChannelContainer } from './ChannelContainer';
export { default as ChannelListContainer } from './ChannelListContainer';
```

This is the ChannelListContainer.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

console.log("hi")

const ChannelListContainer = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            ChannelListContainer
            </div>
    );
}

export default ChannelListContainer;
```

This is the ChannelContainer:

```
import React from 'react';

console.log("hi")
const ChannelContainer = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            ChannelContainer
            </div>
    );
}

export default ChannelContainer;
```

I've googled for hours. I added a "homepage": "./", in my package.json in between  "private": true, and "dependencies": { but that didn't help. I cd into the client folder, then the my-app folder. Then I do npm start but the create-react-app page is blank even though the terminal says that it compiled successfully. I even put console.log("hi") everywhere but nothing shows up on the screen.

Edited: I fixed ID to Id, but the page is still blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo within index.js

Replace `document.getElementByID()` with `document.getElementById()`

A message in the console should show you an error

Comment: @James Yes, you have made a typo. Fix it first. the project is working fine

Comment: I fixed that but it the react app is still blank.

Comment: Are you sure your `Chat` component is being rendered ? Is there anything else in the console ?

Comment: The console says this:

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
    at useState (react.development.js:1507:1)
    at useChat (useChat.js:56:1)
    at Chat (Chat.js:13:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)